# Якраз meaning "actually"

Tags: різниця-між-словами, граматика, non-native-speaker

So in these examples:

1. він якраз в магазині зараз.
2. Я якраз хотіла зробити пару знімків того критого мосту по дорозі.
3. Якраз ії я розумію

I've seen people translate this usage of "якраз" as "actually". Then in this case, what would the difference be if I'd used instead "насправді"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dictionaries, indeed, translate *якраз* as *actually*. The problem is that both *якраз* and *actually* have several different meanings that do not perfectly match:

- *Actually* (1) = really; in fact;

  > I will check what you're *actually* doing.

  A good Ukrainian equivalent for this meaning would be *насправді*.
- *Actually* (2) = the truth is; surprisingly:

  > I thought he's tall. *Actually*, he's short.

  Here, *actually* = *якраз*.

As you may expect, words that have several meanings would not always retain all these meanings when translated.

Ukrainian *якраз* has a certain overlap with the English one, but not precisely. I believe it is better to explain it with short dialogues.

- *Якраз* (1) = right at the moment; right at the opportunity.

  Moment:

  > — You said he will go to the shop.
  > — You caught me right at the moment when he **is** in the shop. — *Він **якраз** у магазині*

  Opportunity:

  > — Let's go to a neighboring town.
  > — Good idea, I *just* wanted to take a photo of that covered bridge in the midway — Я *якраз* хотіла зробити пару знімків того критого мосту по дорозі.

  Note that *він якраз у магазині* can be the opportunity, too:

  > — I forgot to buy milk.
  > — Call him to buy it for you. He's at the shop right now.
- *Якраз* (2) = on the contrary; surprisingly;

  Imagine a dialog:

  > — I understand her.
  > — No, you said don't understand anyone.
  > — (yes, I agree that I don't understand anyone, but) I **do** understand her nevertheless. — ***Якраз** ії я розумію*
- *Якраз* (3) = fit for

  There's one more meaning of *якраз*, just for completeness:

  > These shoes *fit for* me — Ці туфлі мені *якраз*.

Comment: Thanks for the great answer. About the second meaning, if I'd used "якраз таки", would it fundamentally change the meaning, or only add a "although one can think so". From my experience it's used for objections or clarification of something. But asking just in case.

Comment: @ЛугеУшчимі, you're absolutely right. [*Таки*](http://sum.in.ua/s/taky) is a conjunction to provide several meanings. one of which (#3 in linked page) is to denote objection. And #4 for emphasis. Combining it in "*якраз-таки*" does not change the meaning but it emphasizes the effect. I should also say that many people use this conjunction intuitively, so it's more matter of taste than of the hard rules.